# Javascript conditional show/hide div based on other div's content

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to dynamically hide content from users who are not at least on a certain level.

All users can see level 1 content, but they will need to reach a higher level in order to see more content.

The level will be generated inside an html tag (id="level") through the use of a Wordpress plugin shortcode. The content for level 2 or higher will be hidden by default in the html div tag (id="myDiv").

I'm trying to change the style display property from myDiv through a javascript function.

```js
function myFunction()
{
  var myDiv = document.GetElementById("myDiv");
  var level = document.GetElementById("level").innerHTML;
  if (level >= 2) {
      myDiv.style.display  = "block";
  } else {
    myDiv.style.display  = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="myFunction();">
  <div id="level">2</div>
  <div id="myDiv" style="display:none;">myDiv content</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this in the front end. It's trivial to bypass the restriction - anybody can just open the developer tools and remove your protection. You should instead do the filtering on the backend and only give users the content they have access to.

Comment: Also: `GetElementById` should be `getElementById`

Comment: You should also [not be using inline HTML event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) and avoid using inline CSS styles and instead add/remove/toggle CSS classes via the [`.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for highlighting this. Access is indeed managed from the backend, I'm only trying to manage visibility here. 
Access is granted/dripped on basis of a timeline, and I don't want users to see links to content they have not yet been granted access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element.innerHTML` will always return a `string`, try converting your innerHTML to a number using `Number(level)`

```
function myFunction()
{    
    let myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    let stringLevel = document.getElementById("level").textContent;
    const level = Number(stringLevel);
    if (level >= 2) {
        myDiv.style.display  = "block";
    } else {
        myDiv.style.display  = "none";
    }
}
```

(EDIT)

consider using textContent instead of innerHTML as pointed by [Scott Marcus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695364/scott-marcus)

Comment: Better yet, don't use `.innerHTML` at all and use `.textContent` since `.innerHTML` engages the HTML parser and introduces security and performance concerns.